# Rails: Execution expired (and memory error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, heroku

Using: Rails 3.0.3 & Heroku & Execution Notifier & New Relic

I get a lot of execution expired all throughout my website. I have recently realized that I have a part of the website that caused an infinite loop (and thus a memory error).

Question #1: Is it very likely that, when this infinite loop occured, that it would affect the entire website making all others have to wait for it to stop/crash and thus causing them execution expired (which I believe is 30 sec at Heroku).

Question #2: It seems like my website is quite slow. Can you recommend any service I can use to pinpoint what is actually taking time? I have seen some graphical service before with columns on how much each part took to load (like image2 = 3 ms, this javascript = 3002 ms and so on). How else can I troubleshoot or handle Execution Expired errors (referrals to good guides etc is appreciated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) likely depends on how many dynos you have, but if it's a common issue then they could potentially all be locked up simultaneously.

2) New Relic is excellent. It'll let you pinpoint slow actions, drill in and inspect queries, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Regardin #1, I expect that infinite loop occur pretty much with the same frequency as the errors occured (a couple of times per day). I have two dynos. Basically what I need answer to is if this should be a very likely reason for the Execution Expired-error (and thus being solved now) or if I need to trouble shoot more. As I can see it now is only to wait and see if I still get these errors after fixing the infinite loop.

Comment: Regarding #2. I did not know I could use New Relic other than the weekly report, which is interesting but does not really help me to understand more than some things are not running in an optimal way.

Comment: Re #2. Checked out New Relic on the Heroku website and it is truly awesome, pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: Great. Yeah I think to get some of the more useful performance tools you have to spring for the Pro version but sometimes you can squash your main performance issues during the free trial and then downgrade for the basic features.